# Fresnel Diffraction and Fourier Transforms

Tags: mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

I'm reading through Paganin's Coherent X-Ray optics textbook and could use a hand with Fourier Transform (FT) manipulation. For the duration of this post, $\mathcal{F}$ is the forward FT and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is the inverse transform. I define the conventions at the bottom of this post.

In the text, Paganin defines the angular-spectrum representation of a propagated wave-field as

\begin{equation}
\psi_\omega (x, y, z=\Delta) \approx \exp(ik\Delta) \mathcal{F}^{-1} \exp\bigg[\dfrac{-i\Delta (k_x^2 + k_y^2)}{2k} \bigg]\mathcal{F} \psi_\omega (x, y, z=0)
\end{equation}

Here, $\Delta$ is a spatial coordinate and $\Delta > 0$. In the discussion of the convolution formulation of the Fresnel Diffraction section, he defines the following form of convolution:
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) *g(x,y) = 2\pi \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big( \{ \mathcal{F} [f(x, y)]\} \times \{ \mathcal{F}[g(x,y)] \} \big).
\end{equation}

I'm a little confused with what Paganin does after this. He states that *we can rewrite the angular-spectrum representation of the wavefield in the following suggestive form*:
\begin{align}
\psi_\omega (x, y, z=\Delta)
&=
2\pi \mathcal{F}^{-1} \bigg( \dfrac{\exp(ik\Delta)}{2\pi} \exp\bigg[ \dfrac{-ik\Delta(k_x^2 + k_y^2)}{2k} \bigg]  \times \{ \mathcal{F} [\psi_\omega (x, y, z=0] \} \bigg)
\\[.5em]
&=
2\pi \mathcal{F}^{-1} \bigg( \bigg\{ \mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}^{-1} \dfrac{\exp(ik\Delta)}{2\pi} \exp\bigg[\dfrac{-i\Delta(k_x^2 + k_y^2)}{2k} \bigg] \bigg\} \times \{ \mathcal{F} [\psi_\omega (x, y, z=0)] \} \bigg)
\end{align}

I've tried to work out how he does this, but I haven't had any luck. Does anyone have any insight into how we go from the first equation listed to the one just before this sentence?

Since there are a million ways to write the FT, I'll write the definition Paginin uses.
\begin{align}
f(x,y)
&=
\frac{1}{2\pi} \iint_{-\infty}^\infty \tilde{f}(k_x,k_y)\exp[i(k_x x + k_y y)] \, dk_x \, dk_y
\\[.5em]
\tilde{f}(k_x,k_y) 
&=
\frac{1}{2\pi} \iint_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\exp[-i(k_x x + k_y y)] \, dx \, dy
\end{align}
Here, $\tilde{f}$ is the FT of $f$. i.e., $\tilde f=\mathcal{F}[f]$ and ${f}=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\tilde f]$.

Comment: The first equality seems to just be moving $e^{i k \Delta}$ inside the inverse Fourier transform, which is allowed since it's just a scalar. The second equality just seems to be writing $f=\mathcal{F}[\tilde{f}]=\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}^{-1}[f]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\F{\mathcal{F}}
\def\Fi{\F^{-1}} 
\def\p{\pi}
\def\D{\Delta}$Schematically, we have
\begin{align*}
\psi &= 2\p A\Fi(B\F C) 
= 2\p\Fi(AB\F C) 
= 2\p\Fi(\F(\Fi AB)\F C) \\
&= (\Fi AB)\star C
= (A\Fi B)\star C. 
\end{align*}
Note that $A = e^{i k\D}/(2\p)$ is not a function of $x,y$.